# Google Chrome sync error on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.4 and Google Chrome 6.0.472.53.

I've been having an issue where I will setup the sync and everything is fine. I can click on the close button in the upper left-hand corner to close the Chrome window. When I open it later, the sync process is working.

However, when I quit Chrome and later open it, the sync process breaks. Here is the website address to a screenshot of the error:

http://davidsscreenshots.posterous.com/google-chrome-sync-error-on-mac

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I have submitted this as a bug and is recorded as issue 53118.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. Stop syncing to a Google Account in Chrome through the preferences.
2. Quit Chrome. Open Keychain Access and delete Chrome Safe Storage.
3. Open Google Chrome. Enable syncing.

Result: Chrome no longer produces a sync error when it's restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a beta/dev version-related bug. Someone asked in [that referenced bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=53118) if you had upgraded, etc. but didn't ask if you had down-graded. When you went back to the stable channel, did you delete the Chrome plist before testing?

`~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`

It may be that the sync portion of the plist differs between builds.

Comment: I had just downgraded today, but no, I did not delete that file. I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried closing Chrome and deleting the file you had mentioned, but that didn't fix the issue.

I thought I'd try taking it a step further and completely uninstalling Google Chrome. I dragged the Chrome icon from the Applications folder into the Trash. Then I deleted the file you mentioned. Finally, deleted the entire Chrome folder from the following location:

~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome

After doing all that, I reinstalled Chrome. Without restoring anything, I started Chrome, setup the syncing, and quit out of it. When I started it up, the same issue occurred.

Comment: For testing purposes, I downloaded the latest snapshot build of Chromium. It seems to suffer from the same issue. I'm guessing this issue isn't too common because I have yet to hear from anyone else experiencing it.

Comment: Can you verify a few more things?

1. Do you have an active Google Docs account?
2. Which options are you syncing? Have you tried "Keep everything synced?" and have you tried it with just specific checkboxes?
3. If the two previous don't work, could you change your Google password and retry syncing? Please try all of this after deleting the aforementioned preference and support files, using the STABLE build.

Comment: Initially, I was only syncing bookmarks. So I completely uninstalled Chrome again and deleted all of the aforementioned files. I then reinstalled Chrome, enabled sync, and chose to sync everything. Then I restarted Chrome and the same issue occurred. One thing I noticed is that Chrome synced my bookmarks and preferences, but not my extensions.

Then I reset my password and tried the syncing again. After restarting, the same error occurred.

On my Chrome issue post, they asked me to "start Chrome with the --user-data-dir=<give_name_of_local_directory> and try syncing?" Not sure what that means.

Comment: I also use Chrome on a Windows XP machine. I'm not sure if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: I've also tried syncing with a different Google account. Same outcome.

Comment: That switch they gave you is a command-line option that I've only seen in the Windows environment (although you may be able to pass it to Chrome by launching it from the Terminal).

In Windows, go to the Chrome shortcut you use and right-click > Properties > Shortcut. In the Target box, you'd add a space after Chrome.exe and then copy and paste that string they gave you. See this image for an example (http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/image8.png).

Comment: If it can be done in Terminal, you'd type `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=<give_name_of_local_directory>`

Comment: Again, please do all testing in the current stable release of chrome.

*I really hope this works out for you--it's quite an ordeal!*

Comment: So I've tried a few different things to try and accomplish the Terminal command and I always come up short. I tried the following command:

open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --user-data-dir=/Users/Levine/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/

After typing that in and pressing enter, I received the following error:

open: unrecognized option `--user-data-dir=/Users/Levine/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/'

Comment: Then I tried the following command:

'open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --user-data-dir=/Users/Levine/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default'

And received the following error:

-bash: open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --user-data-dir=/Users/Levine/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default: No such file or directory

Thanks for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Haha. How did it go in the Windows test?

Comment: I don't have an issue with the Windows version syncing, which I use on a work laptop that I don't have with me. This issue only occurs on the Mac version which is what I use at home.

Comment: I figured it out after reading another post on Super User. I entered:

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/Levine/Documents/Google\ Chrome

It launches Chrome using a new profile. Unfortunately, the same error occurred when I quit Chrome and launched it again using the same Terminal command.

Comment: Make another Google account and sync with it to see if it's related to your specific account. If the problem goes away, I bet there's some problem with your sync data in the "cloud".

Comment: I tried two things. I tried syncing with another Google account I already have using my existing profile. When I did this, I still got the sync error after restarting Chrome.

Then I created a completely new Google account and used the Terminal command to open Chrome with a new profile. After I synced with this new account and restarted Chrome, the same sync error occurred. During this new instance of Chrome, I accepted all defaults and synced everything.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Make a new user account in OS X and try it there with the stable version.

Comment: I created a new account and it does not exhibit the sync failure after restarting Chrome. I hope you know what is causing this issue so I do not have to create a new account to fix it.